# Every non-measurable $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has non-measurable $Y \subseteq X$ such that $|Z|=0$ for every measurable $Z \subseteq Y$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to argue that a Lebesgue non-measurable subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a non-measurable subset $Y$ such that any measurable subset of $Y$ has measure zero.

Let $A_0$ be a measurable subset of $X$. If all such $A_0$ has measure zero, then let $Y = X$ and we are done. Otherwise, choose $A_0$ which has positive measure. By Vitali construction, there exists a non-measurable subset $A_1 \subset A_0$. Again, if $A_1$ doesn't have a measurable subset of positive measure, then set $Y = A_1$. Otherwise, we repeat what we did as above.

How does one rigorously conclude that the process will have to eventually terminate?

Comment: That process is too loosely-defined to be guaranteed to terminate - maybe we just happen to keep grabbing "inefficient" subsets of our starting set. I would recommend thinking in the opposite direction: actively try to carve out a "maximal(ish) measurable subset" (and think about what's left over).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Using your suggestion, I try something along this line - let $A_0$ be a maximal measurable subset of $X$, i.e., if $A \subset X$ is measurable and contains $A_0$, then $A = A_0$. We know that $A_1 = X-A_0$ is not measurable, otherwise $|X| = |A_0|+|A_1|$. Now $A_1$ cannot contain a subset $A_2$ of positive measure, otherwise $|A_0+A_2| > |A_0|$ which contradicts maximality. Hence $A_1$ is the desired set. Would this work?

Comment: How do you know a maximal measurable subset exists? (It probably *won't* - this is why I wrote "maximal(ish)" in my original comment. You need something a bit more subtle.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well how about the union of all the measurable subsets of $X$? Or perhaps we just consider the union of all measurable subsets of positive measure. In this case it wouldn't be maximal in the set containment sense, but it would have the largest positive measure.

Comment: The union of all the measurable subsets of $X$ is just $X$, since every singleton is measurable. The same holds for the positive measure subsets, since adding a single point won't change measurability. You can't be too greedy here; you need a "soft" notion of maximality. Can you show that there is a measurable subset of $X$ which, while perhaps not *literally* maximal, does have maximal measure amongst measurable subsets of $X$? *(A useful point here will be that measurability is preserved by taking **countable** unions.)*

Comment: @NoahSchweber This idea of maximality smells like Zorn's lemma to me though. Maybe we consider subsets $E_i$ of $X$ of positive measure, and order the chain by its measure, i.e., $|E_1| \leq |E_1 \cup E_2| \leq ...$. In this case the upper bound would be the union of all $E_i$'s, but then again I can't guarantee that we are talking about countably many of them.

Comment: You really **don't** want to use Zorn here, but thinking about a chain of increasingly large measurable sets is moving on the right track. I think this has gone far enough that I'm turning my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following turns my comments above into an answer (modulo exercises :P).

*Throughout, I'll assume that $X$ is a non-measurable set which has a positive-measure measurable subset.*

The process in the OP is too loosely-defined to be guaranteed to terminate - maybe we just happen to keep grabbing "inefficient" subsets of our starting set. Instead, it's better to try to carve out a "maximal(ish) measurable subset" (and think about what's left over).

Note my careful use of the suffix "ish" in the above. There is not going to be a *literally maximal* measurable subset of $X$: if $A\subseteq X$ is measurable and $a\in X\setminus A$, then $A\cup\{a\}$ is also a measurable subset of $X$. Similarly, we can't do something like taking the union of all the positive-measure subsets of $X$: that will just yield $X$ itself (again thinking about how singletons don't affect measurability), which isn't measurable. This second obstacle brings up a related issue, namely that measurability is *fragile*: if I take a union of a bunch of measurable sets, the result may not be measurable. Only **countable unions** are safe: the union of countably many measurable sets is always guaranteed to be measurable.

So we want to find a measurable subset of $X$ which in some sense is as big as possible, but $(i)$ that sense has to be somewhat nuanced and $(ii)$ we have to only take a small number (= countably many) of unions of measurable pieces. What can we do?

Well, besides literal maximality, we do have at hand a way of measuring when something is as big as possible: **measure**! Say that $A\subseteq X$ is a **quasimaximal-measurable** subset of $X$ (not an actual term) iff $A$ is measurable and, for every measurable $B$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$, we have $m(A)=m(B)$ (or equivalently, if $B$ is any measurable subset of $X$ we have $m(A)\ge m(B)$). **So maybe $A$ isn't literally as big as possible, but we can't do any better measure-wise.**

Using basic facts about measurability, you should be able to prove the following statements:

1. If $A$ is a quasimaximal-measurable subset of $X$, then $X\setminus A$ is non-null.
2. If $A$ is a quasimaximal-measurable subset of $X$, then $X\setminus A$ does not have a positive-measure measurable subset.

At this point you're basically done ... **except** that you need to prove that quasimaximal-measurable subsets exist at all! HINT: consider the number $$\alpha=\sup\{m(A): A\subseteq X\mbox{ is measurable}\}$$ (for simplicity let's assume $\alpha<\infty$). Can you see how to build a measurable subset of $X$ with measure exactly $\alpha$ (think about countable unions!), and why such a subset must be quasimaximal-measurable?

Comment: If $X-A$ is null, then $X$ is has measure $|A|$, a contradiction. If $X-A$ has a subset $B$ of positive measure, then $A \cup B$ has measure greater than $A$, contradicting maximality. The second part seems to suggest that we already exhausted all positive-measure measurable subsets, which seems to me as though we considered the union of all such subsets to construct $A$, which you already said was not the case. I can show that the set of disjoint positive-measure subsets of $X$ is countable, using properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I can't show that the set of all such subsets is countable.

Comment: See [Decomposition of Unmeasurable Sets into Measurable and Purely Unmeasurable Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3511898/13130). FYI, I believe this result first appeared in Waldemar Alexandrow (1890-1983)'s 1915 Ph.D. dissertation [**Elementare Grundlagen für die Theorie des Maßes**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/011678251) under Zermelo, and it was independently obtained by Witold Wilkosz (1891-1941) in [*Sugli insiemi non misurabili* $L$](https://eudml.org/doc/212589) (1920). **(continued)**

Comment: The term "non-measurable kernel" is used in Solomon's [*On non-measurable sets*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-36/issue-1/On-non-measurable-sets/10.1215/S0012-7094-69-03625-4.short). Other places this idea occurs are: Albanese (1974), Blumberg (1935), Froda (1936), Jeffery (1932), Morgan's 1990 book **Point Set Theory** (see 4.III.E), Zaubek (1943-44), Zermelo (1927). Space and time limitations prevent me from being more specific . . .