# Is there a concept of "local" measurability?

Tags: measure-theory

Measurability of functions between measurable spaces is defined so very similarly to the continuity for topological spaces. However, we also have a fruitful notion of "continuity at a point $x_0$" in topology—"points nearby $x_0$ get mapped to point nearby $f(x_0)$".

I was wondering if there's a parallel for this in measure theory. If so, what does it represent?

Comment: I've never seen it used, but we can easily mirror the topological definition of [continuous at a point](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuous_Mapping_(Topology)) in the measurable world. In that case we would say that $f : (X, \mathcal{F}) \to (Y, \mathcal{G})$ is _measurable at_ $x$ iff for every measurable $E' \in \mathcal{G}$ containing $f(x)$, there is a measurable $E \in \mathcal{F}$ containing $x$ with $f[E] \subseteq E'$. I'm not sure of applications, but you could almost certainly port theorems about continuity at a point to measurability at a point without much effort.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I had the same hunch.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Your definition would make every function measurable at every point, provided that single points are measurable, since you could always take $E=\{x\}$.

Comment: @MW -- that certainly agrees with my remark that I've never seen this studied :P

Comment: ([*20 Jan 2020 comment*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3511898/13130)) Of related interest is the notion of points of non-measurability of a set. See [this 25 Nov 1999 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/F4gazq30DKI/m/8cTImYk8WVcJ) and the follow-up posts in the same thread. I know of at least 10 references to this notion if anyone is interested, the 2nd earliest and most detailed being [*Sugli insiemi non misurabili L*](https://eudml.org/doc/212589) by Wiltold Wilkosz (1920), of which (again, if anyone is interested) I have translations of its theorem statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, the problem with trying this analogy for measure spaces is that very often, we want points themselves to be measurable, and then in a measure-theoretic sense, they all become interchangeable.

To more precisely illustrate the difficulty here, suppose we are studying measurable spaces (i.e, pairs $(X,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of sets) for which singletons are measurable.

Suppose further that we wish to have some definition for measurability-at-a-point of a function $f\colon X\to X'$ between two such spaces $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(X',\Sigma')$ satisfying the following reasonable properties, in analogy with continuity at a point vs continuity.

1. $f$ is measurable at every point $x\in X$ if and only if $f$ is measurable.
2. Whenever $g\colon X_1\to X_2$ is a measurable equivalence (i.e., a measurable bijection with measurable inverse), then $f\colon X_1\to X'$ is measurable at $p$ if and only if $f\circ g^{-1}$ is measurable at $g(p)$.
3. Whenever $h\colon X'\to X''$ is a measurable equivalence, then $f\colon X\to X'$ is measurable at $p$ if and only if $h\circ f$ is measurable at $p$.

The problem becomes that these properties completely trivialize the notion of pointwise measurability, at least in the case of bijections.  That is, from just the preceding three properties and the measurability of singletons we have

> **Theorem.**  Let $f\colon X\to X'$ be a bijection between nonempty measurable spaces with measurable singletons.  Then $f$ is measurable if and only if it is measurable at at least one point.

##### Proof

For the proof, one direction is clear, that $f$ "globally" measurable implies $f$ measurable at every point in $X$, hence we may pick an arbitrary point.  Conversely, suppose $f$ is measurable at $x$, and $y\in X$ is arbitrary.  Now for all $p,q\in X$ the map $g_{pq}\colon X\to X$ defined by
$$ g(z)=
\begin{cases}
q & z=p\\
p & z=q\\
z & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is clearly a measurable equivalence (this follows quickly from the measurability of singletons).

But observe then that $f= g_{f(x)f(y)}\circ f\circ g_{xy}$, which is measurable at $y$ by properties #2 and #3, so $f$ is measurable at every point, and so property #1 tells us that $f$ is measurable.